puppeteer generated pdf How to display content at the bottom of the last page
puppeteer pdf generation
I wanted to implement the end of the page function, but there was no good solution, We hope to get help from the community.
code：
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .content {
        background-color: #999;
      }
      .footer {
        background-color: #e9a530;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>tabe header 1</td>
            <td>tabe header 2</td>
            <td>tabe header 3</td>
            <td>tabe header 4</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">tabe content 5</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">table footer</td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      I want the footer at the bottom of the print page
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

When I print a page using chrome, I want the footer to be at the bottom of the current page, the data to be dynamic, and the pagination to be potentially multiple pages
chrome print page
I tried to
'css position fixed' and 'Calculate content height based on DOM's scrollHeight and offsetTop',
However, the content contains 'table thead tfoot' and 'page-break-inside', and the positioning is inaccurate.
